# android: how do I format number as phone with parentheses

Tags: android, phone-number, number-formatting, libphonenumber

I have a number that I need to format as a telephone number. If I do

```
 PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(numStr);
```

Then I get

```
888-555-1234
```

But what I need to get is

```
(888) 555-1234
```

How do I get the second one? Is there a standard android way?

Comment: Are you only targetting North american numbers ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you know the country for which you want to do it, you can use Google's open source library [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) . Here is how you can format it:

```
String numberStr = "8885551234"
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(numberStr, "US");
  //Since you know the country you can format it as follows:
  System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(numberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL));
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

If you don't know the country then for `numberStr` use [E.164 format phone number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) and in place of country code use null.

Answer (score 12):

Don't know if you found what you were looking for, but I ended up writing a little method that takes the length of a string (since the phone numbers I get come from a web service and can be a variety of formats). I believe it should work (so far all my test cases have been with the first two options -- haven't tested the other two yet).

```
public static String FormatStringAsPhoneNumber(String input) {
    String output;
    switch (input.length()) {
        case 7:
            output = String.format("%s-%s", input.substring(0,3), input.substring(3,7));
            break;
        case 10:
            output = String.format("(%s) %s-%s", input.substring(0,3), input.substring(3,6), input.substring(6,10));
            break;
        case 11:
            output = String.format("%s (%s) %s-%s", input.substring(0,1) ,input.substring(1,4), input.substring(4,7), input.substring(7,11));
            break;
        case 12:
            output = String.format("+%s (%s) %s-%s", input.substring(0,2) ,input.substring(2,5), input.substring(5,8), input.substring(8,12));
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have the String `"888-555-1234"` - by using `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(numStr);` you can simply do this:

```
String numStr = "888-555-1234";

numStr = "(" + numStr.substring(0,3) + ") " + numStr.substring(4);

System.out.print(numStr); // (888) 555-1234
```

However, this is hard coded. You would need to make sure the String had a full 10 digits before doing so.

Answer (score 4):

You simply use this and get you want :

```
new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher()
```

or Have look at this url :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex. [This](https://regex101.com/) will help you. As for me, i use this:

```
                        var result = "+1 888-555-1234"


                        if (Pattern.compile("^\\+[\\d]+\\s[\\d]{1,3}\\s[\\d]+").matcher(result).find()) {
                            result = result.replaceFirst(" ", "(").replaceFirst(" ", ")").replace(" ","-")
                        }

                        if(Pattern.compile("^\\+[\\d]+\\s[\\d]{1,3}-[\\d]+").matcher(result).find()){
                            result = result.replaceFirst(" ", "(").replaceFirst("-", ")")
                        }
                        Timber.d("$result")
```

> output: +1(888)555-1234

Answer (score 0):

Working solution in 2020:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String countryIso = telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso().toUpperCase();

phoneNumberTextView.setText(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber("3473214567", countryIso));
```