# How to limit the input digits length in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I developed an App that asks the user to input ID and Phone number. Using Android, I want to limit the digits of the inputting number. My boxes of type numbers.

Comment: Are you only going to support phone numbers from one country?  Usually for this kind of thing, you want to make it robust so that it works with all countries and their specific phone number formats.  In the past I used Google's libphonenumber (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21271035/4409409 ) and a PhoneNumberFormattingTestWatcher: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html

Comment: thank  you for these links they really help  me a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `android:maxLength` as an attribute in your `EditText`

For example:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="12"/>
```