# Parse Phone Number To show Braces

Tags: android, libphonenumber

I am trying to format a phone number but problem is i am getting - instead of ()

Please let me know how i can fix this.

I am trying this code to format  i am receiving num like this  +1111111111:

```
try
{
    formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(model.getReceiverMobileNumber(), SharedPref.getString(context,SharedPref.country_code));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

My output:

```
+1 111-111-1111
```

but i want

```
+1 (111) 111-1111
```

**thanks**

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270686/android-how-do-i-format-number-as-phone-with-parentheses

Comment: it gives me the correct ans but +1 is not here