# Missing parenthesis when dialing telephone number in android

Tags: java, android, odoo-mobile

I'm trying to use intent to pass a number in dialer but when I tried using telephone numbers, there we're no parenthesis shown for example I have the ff. number `(828) 316-0593` and will show as `8283160593`, it seems parenthesis and dashes are being ignored.

Code:

```
 Uri phone = Uri.parse("tel:" + record.getString("phone"));
 Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, phone);
 startActivity(dial);
```

I also tried using mobile number `+1 123 4512533` but the `'+'` symbol still shown after passing to dialer.

When I used an emulator, it shows the same format when I open the dialer but when I try to used a physical device, it doesn't show the same.

How can I make the same output after passing to dialer? Which of these(emulator, physical) shows the correct output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android: how do I format number as phone with parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270686/android-how-do-i-format-number-as-phone-with-parentheses)

Comment: Valid US formats are `(828) 316-0593` or `828-316-0593`, not `(828)-316-0593`

Comment: @Wini I also tried  android: how do I format number as phone with parentheses but it doesn't work when I tried using physical device

Answer (score 0):

Probably be it depends on the operating system. But you wont be able to face any error form it.

Comment: think so, but mostly it should output the same right? either physical or emulator